# React — nested onClick handlers?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button component inside a parent component and need the button component to handle button style onClick of the button **element**, while the parent handles click of the Btn **component**.

I've got the clickHandler working in the Btn component, but not the parent. What's the best way to do this?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/50380/)

```
// button component
class BtnFav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {favorited: false};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({favorited: !this.state.favorited});
  }
  render() {
    var btnStyle = this.state.favorited ? 'btn-fav' : 'btn-notfav';
    var btnText = this.state.favorited ? 'FAVORITED' : 'NOT FAVORITED';
    return (
      <button className={btnStyle} onClick={this.handleClick}>{btnText}</button>
    );
  }
};
// parent
class BtnParent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.alsoDoThis = this.alsoDoThis.bind(this);
  }
  alsoDoThis() {
    alert('Also do this.');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BtnFav onClick={this.alsoDoThis} />
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <BtnParent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: You should add this.props.onClick in your handleClick method, jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50386

Comment: That did it! Thank you kindly :)